# Using C# to add stored procedures from solution folder to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my Visual Studio (C#) solution I have a folder named `stored procedures` with a large number of `.sql` files containing T-SQL.

Here's an example:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Foo Bar
-- Create date: 28-12-2016
-- Description: Create XrefUsers
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateXrefUsers] 
AS
BEGIN
```

I wish to add all these stored procedures to my database.

So I copied all the `.sql` files, renamed the copies to .tt (T4 file extension) and set `TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor` as customtool.

Now I wrote this code, to add the stored procedures:

```
public bool AddStoredProcedures()
{
    try
    {
        //spCreateXrefUsers_sql.tt
        CreateStoredProcedure(new spCreateXrefUsers_sql().TransformText());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static void CreateStoredProcedure(string spText)
{
    var connectionString = MigrateHelpers.GetConnectionStringQA();
    //var commandText = string.Format("EXEC sp_executesql {0}", spText);                

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spText, connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

I have read: [GO (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

So I tried:

```
spText = spText.Replace("GO", "");
```

But that still leaves me with the

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

error.

What should I change in my code, to be able to execute the T-SQL?

I am probably doing it all wrong. Please enlighten me!

Perhaps I should create a new [SQL CLR database project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxsa8hkf(v=vs.100).aspx)

When I open the .SQL file in Visual Studio I am able to execute => create the Stored Procedure manually. Then I should be able to do it from code right?
[image]

Comment: You are working in a Visual Studio Database Project. You know that you can deploy those scripts without a custom tool, right?

Comment: It actually is not a VS Database project.

Comment: Couple of things, when you create your procedure scripts be sure to drop (if exists) and then create so that running the script is repeatable, also include any grant statements needed to ensure the proper security. Then when looking for the word 'GO' understand the Microsoft rules of where it can be in your scripts. See link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx . Sounds like in your case you may have one script missing it's terminating GO statement.

Answer (score 1):

if all you're looking for is a way to bulk load your procs you can do it from a cmd line. I create a batch file that has a "sqlcmd" line for file example below. The cmd below is using windows auth but you can change it to use a sql login. sqlcmd can be found in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn/sqlcmd.EXE"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

sqlcmd -S server -d database -E -b -m-1 -r 1 -h-1 -i c:\temp\spCreateXrefUsers.sql

Comment: I do not want to work with file path! I am 100% allergic to using file path.

Comment: Excuse my ignorant comment. I can just call sqlcmd from C# code, and write the .sql files to a temp folder and execute them from that path. Thank you! I will see if this works for me.